# dsconfigad: Node name wasn't found. (2000)

Tags: active-directory, directory-utility

When I rejoined domain after already joined domain successfully with `dsconfigad`, it's failed with

> dsconfigad: Node name wasn't found. (2000)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's caused by incorrect time, fixed by `sudo ntpdate -u time.apple.com`